# Why is this not recognized as a valid datetime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following line of code:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("‎2017/‎04/‎09 ‏‎2:44 PM", "yyyy/MM/dd h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As you can see the datetime and the format matches (well at least it appears to match), yet I still get an error when converting:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure where you took it, but there are a few invisible unicode characters in your input. Try copy-pasting this and it'll work:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact("2017/04/09 2:44 PM", "yyyy/MM/dd h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Digging further, there is a "E2 80 8E" between / and 0, and another one just before the 2. [According to the unicode table](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128), this is "left-to-right mark".

One way to make it work is to remove all the characters you don't expect to see:

```
var input = "‎2017/‎04/‎09 ‏‎2:44 PM";

var sanitizedInput = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\w:/ ]", string.Empty);

DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(sanitizedInput, "yyyy/MM/dd h:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The thing is I get it from  the "Date last saved" value from explorer. And the original string had '?' symbols which I replaced with string.Empty

Comment: @Eminem If you can't get a clean string from the source, one solution is to sanitize it. See my edit